# How to stop a class setting a property to its literal name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3.7, there is a class I don't fully understand that I need to use.
I want to set its properties to corresponding ones in a dictionary I built in a loop, as it seems to be the cleanest method I can think of.

E.g:

```
ex_dict = {'part1': 1, 'part2': 2}
for x in ex_dict:
    ex_class.x = ex_dict[x]
```

which instead of setting

`ex_class.part1 = 1`,

sets

`ex_class.x = 1`

and then

`ex_class.x = 2`

Is it possible to fanangle this in another manner? I have been setting them individually and that's fine, but there are many keys to set. The class itself is long and I don't know what information is relevent to add here I'm afraid.

Comment: [`setattr(classInstance, attribute, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) will set `attribute` on `classInstance`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for x in ex_dict:
    setattr(ex_class, x, ex_dict[x])
```